# Checking/un-checking a checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a checkbox between checked and un-checked using the following code, but it seems to only un-check.

```
var checkbox = $this.find('[name="category"]');

if ('checkbox:checked') {
    checkbox.prop("checked", false);
} else {
    checkbox.prop("checked", true);
}
```

How can I make it toggle correctly?

Is there a better way to do this instead of doing if/else statements? .toggle() doesn't seem to work for checkboxes correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Toggle function like

```
$('[name="category"]').toggle(
 function() { 
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true); },
 function() { 
    $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
 });
```

or

just try like this

```
   var checkbox = $this.find('[name="category"]'); 
   $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
```

or for jquery 1.6

```
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears to be only one element, just use `checkbox.checked`

```
var checkbox = $this.find('[name="category"]').get(0);

checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
```

Comment: It's actually a table full of posts, so there are a lot of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 if (checkbox.is(':checked')) { ... }
```

or

```
checkbox.prop('checked', checkbox.is(':checked'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
```

or, a bit more complicated:

```
if ($this.find('[name="category"]:checked').length) {
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 0):

You need to revisit your IF statement. You are basically checking for a string 'checked:checked'

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkbox = $this.find('[name="category"]');
checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.is(":checked") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
checkbox.prop('checked', checkbox.is(':checked'));
```